# Prove that the following are not inner products.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inner-products, education, axioms

Show that each of the following
(a) <u, v> = u<sub>1</sub> v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub> v<sub>2</sub>; and (b) <u, v> = u<sub>1</sub> v<sub>2</sub> u<sub>3</sub> + v<sub>1</sub> u<sub>2</sub> v<sub>3</sub>

is not an inner product on $ℝ^3$, where u = (u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, u<sub>3</sub>) and v = (v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>).

A function is an inner product if it satisfies the axioms:

1. <u,v> = <v,u>
2. <u,v+w> = <u,w> + <u,w>
3. c<u,v>=<cu,v>
4. <v,v>=0 and <v,v>=0 ⇔ v=0

(a) <u,v> = u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>

Solution:

<u,v> = u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>

<u,v> = v<sub>1</sub>u<sub>1</sub> + v<sub>2</sub>u<sub>2</sub> (Commutativity)

<u,v> = <v,u> (Axiom 1 satisfied).

Let w=(w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub>)
<u,v+w> = <(u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>), (v<sub>1</sub> + w<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub> + w<sub>2</sub>)>

<u,v+w> = u<sub>1</sub> (v<sub>1</sub> + w<sub>1</sub>)+ u<sub>2</sub> (v<sub>2</sub> + w<sub>2</sub>)

<u,v+w> = (u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>) + (u<sub>1</sub>w<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>w<sub>2</sub>)

<u,v+w> = <u,v> + <u,w> (Axiom 2 satisfied).

Let c∈ℝ, then

c<u,v> = c(u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>)

c<u,v> = (cu<sub>1</sub>)v<sub>1</sub> + cu<sub>2</sub>(v<sub>2</sub>)

c<u,v> = <cu,v> (Axiom 3 satisfied).

<v,v> = v<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + v<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> ≥ 0

Moreover, <v,v> = 0

⇔ v<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + v<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> = 0

⇔ v<sub>1</sub> = v<sub>2</sub> = 0 since v<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> ≥ 0,
v<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> ≥ 0

⇔ v = (0, 0) (Axiom 4 satisfied).

Therefore, <u,v> = = u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub> is an inner product on $ℝ^3$.

Am I doing the right thing in (a)? I'm not sure about it. However, I am stuck in (b). Am I going to do the same process for (b)?

Comment: For part $a$, keep in mind that these are $3-$dimensional vectors, not $2$.  What is $(0,0,1)\cdot (0,0,1)$?

Comment: I am sorry, @lulu. I'm only new to inner products that's why I'm confused.

Comment: No need to apologize!  At first glance it does look like part $a$ concerns two dimensional vectors,  in which case this would simply be the standard Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb R^2$.  But a closer reading reveals that they really mean three dimensional vectors, so the proposed inner product would be $(u_1,u_2,u_3)\cdot (v_1,v_2,v_3)=u_1v_1+u_2v_2$.

Comment: Should say:  you have a typo.  for your part $4$ of the definition, you meant to write $<\vec 0,\vec 0>=0$ not $<v,v>=0$.  Or you could omit that completely since it is covered by $<v,v>=0\iff v=\vec 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a) use the comment by lulu.

For b) take $u=(1,1,-1)$ and note that $ \langle u, u \rangle <0$.